# How does Redis client/connection limit work on Heroku RedisCloud?

Tags: heroku, redis, add-on

So, I have a Java app on Heroku that uses RedisCloud addon. 
The addon clearly states that the free version comes with a maximum of 30 Connections:

[image: RedisCloud Free Description with 30 connection limit]

The problem is that Im getting this error:

```
ERR max number of clients reached
```

So the first thing I did obviously was check the RedisCloud monitor and to my surprise, It establishes a limit of 10 Connections:

[image: RedisCloud Client Limit]

***The question:***
Why are we getting a connection limit of 10 on RedisCloud when the limit on the Heroku addon says it should be 30?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your add-on is using an old version of the plan from before we launched our [Bigger and Imporved XXXL Free plan](https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-free-30mb) earlier this year.

The easiest way to resolve that is to use the Heroku toolkit belt and run the command:

```
heroku addons:upgrade rediscloud:30 -a <your app's name>
```